# Proof Hints: Teichmüller-Tukey Lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Synopsis**

*Why this is NOT a duplicate (as far as I'm aware).*

After having read the other posts on StackExchange about this lemma, many of them rely on concepts like well-ordering and other things I haven't learned yet. All I have learned so far is the axiom of choice and basic cardinality with nothing related to partial ordering or finite characters. So I hope this is enough justification for asking another question about this lemma. Please provide me with hints that don't utilize the concepts mentioned above.

**Exercise**

(Teichmüller-Tukey lemma) Assume that $\mathscr{A}$ is a nonempty set such that for every set $B$, $$B \in \mathscr{A} \Leftrightarrow \text{every finite subset of $B$ is a member of $\mathscr{A}$.}$$ Show that $\mathscr{A}$ has a maximal element, i.e., an element that is not a subset of any other element of $\mathscr{A}$.

**What I've Tried**

I started with the following attempt to apply Zorn's lemma:

> Consider a chain $\mathscr{B} \subseteq \mathscr{A}$. We wish to show
> that $\bigcup \mathscr{B} \in \mathscr{A}$. Let $x$ be a subset of
> $\bigcup \mathscr{B}$. Then for all $x' \in x$, there exists a set $B
> \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $x' \in B$. So $\{x'\} \subseteq B$ and
> $\{x'\} \in \mathscr{A}$. Since $\{x'\}$ is a subset of $x$ and $\{x'\} \in \mathscr{A}$, then $x \in \mathscr{A}$ since it satisfies the requirements for $\mathscr{A}$. So $\bigcup \mathscr{B} \in \mathscr{A}$ and Zorn's lemma guarantees a maximal element.

Upon further examination, though, I realized that I haven't necessarily proved that *every* subset of $x$ was in $\mathscr{A}$, but only all singleton subsets. So I thought I might have to do something with $\bigcup x$ or maybe invoke the form of the axiom of choice that guarantees a choice function. But I didn't know how to proceed and I confused myself quickly. As such, I would appreciate any hints in showing that $\bigcup \mathscr{B} \in \mathscr{A}$ (assuming that Zorn's lemma is the right path towards the solution). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is a chain. You want to show that every finite subset of $\bigcup\mathscr{B}$ is a member of $\mathscr{A}$, so let $F$ be a finite subset of $\bigcup\mathscr{B}$. For each $x\in F$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x$. $\mathscr{B}$ is a chain, and $F$ is finite, so $\{B_x:x\in F\}$ has a maximum element $B_{x_0}$. But then $x\in B_x\subseteq B_{x_0}$ for each $x\in F$, so $F\subseteq B_{x_0}$. Finally, $B_{x_0}\in\mathscr{A}$, so $F\in\mathscr{A}$, as desired.

Comment: Where do you get the fact that $\{B_x: x \in F\}$ has a maximum element? I haven't encountered chains much yet to be honest, so I was wondering if you could elaborate a little more on that.

Comment: @mijucik: Being a chain in this context simply means that $\mathscr{B}$ is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$. Thus, the sets $B_x$ for $x\in F$ can be linearly ordered by $\subseteq$. If $|F|=n$, say, we can index $F$ as $\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$ in such a way that $B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq\ldots\subseteq B_n$, and $B_n$ is then the maximal element of $\{B_x:x\in F\}$. Every finite subset of a linearly ordered collection automatically has both a maximum and a minimum element.

Comment: @mijucik: I’m really not at all sure that you need to prove that a finite chain has a maximum element, but if you feel that it’s necessary, a proof by induction on the cardinality of the chain would work.

Comment: I see. That makes sense now. Sorry I deleted my past comments because I thought my need for a proof to be unnecessary. Thank you, though, for the suggestion.

Comment: @mijucik: You’re welcome.